# commutative law of monoid

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

can someone help me understand proof of this property?
Let G be a commutative Monoid and $x_1,..,x_n \in G$. Let $\psi$ be a bijection of the set of intergers $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ . Then $$ \prod^n_{v=1}x_{\psi(v)}=\prod^n_{v=1}x_v$$
Assume for $n-1$, let $k$ be the integer s.t   $\psi(k)=n$,
$$ \prod^n_{v=1}x_{\psi(v)}=\prod^{k-1}_{v=1}x_{\psi(v)}*x_{\psi(k)}\prod^{n-k}_{v=1}x_{\psi(v+k)}$$
Define a map $\phi(v) = \psi(v)$ if $ v<k $, else $\phi(v)=\psi(v+1)$ on $\{1,2,...,n-1\}$
Then,
$$ \prod^n_{v=1}x_{\psi(v)}=\prod^{k-1}_{v=1}x_{\phi(v)}*x_{\phi(k)}\prod^{n-k}_{v=1}x_{\phi(v-1+k)}\\=\prod^{n-1}_{v=1}x_{\phi(v)}x_n$$
I'm confused on why do we need to define the map $\phi$ in this proof? I feel like the definition of $\phi$ is redundant. since k-1, n-k < n, and shouldn't the property hold by applying the hypothesis to $\psi$? Thanks!

Comment: Redundant with what? Clearly $\varphi$ is different from $\psi$, right? You must apply  induction hypothesis to something, and that thing is $\varphi$.

Comment: Which book is this from?

Comment: This is from the Serge Lang's Algebra.

Comment: @WhatsUp I see they are different, but I can't figure out why do we need $\phi$. it seems to me that the proof should end before the definition by applying the hypothesis to $\psi$. Been thinking about this whole day, don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: Please do not rely on images to convey crucial information. [See here for an explanation.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Comment: The induction hypothesis applies to a bijection on a set with $n-1$ elements. You need such a bijection to apply it. You could write a different proof with a different induction hypothesis, but then it wouldn't be this proof.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin ah I see, the induction is on the set of numbers instead of the integer itself. ok it makes sense now, thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. You should write out explicitly what the induction hypothesis states (it is a statement that depends on a single value, in this case $n-1$) and verify that you cannot apply it as-is as you initially thought, but instead need some new function to which to apply it.